# How I can add a field in a table m2m field to accumulate that

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

```
def _fojas_utiles(self, cr, ids, name, arg,  uid,  context={} ):
        result={}
        total=0
        for document in self.browse( cr, uid, ids, context={}): 
            job=(document.job_o2m_id.numero_fojas_document)
            total+=job
            result[document.id]= (total)
        return result
```

As I can draw another field of the same document.job.o2m_id.numero_fojas_document and accumulate total

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you mean here.  This code simply seems to be returning the field numero_fojas_document from the related job_o2m_id

In this case it would be simpler to use a related field.

As a general comment, you have a bug in the def statement, "context = {}" should read context = None.  See # 1 here http://www.toptal.com/python/top-10-mistakes-that-python-programmers-make

In the same vein, in the browse call it should read "context = context", not "context = {}" as you are ignoring any context passed into your method.